# How to change an id of a span tag using query?

Tags: javascript

I have a program where everything works except one line. The code is to apply the class "footerStyle" to the span id named "footer1". When working correctly the line in footer1 should increase in size and change font family's.

Code must use querySelector or querySelectorAll

Full code, but code in question is labeled.

LOCATION - THIRD LINE FROM END

```
<style>
        /*class names always begin with a .   */
        .ImportantStuff {
            color: red;
            font-family: Britannic;
            font-size: xx-large;
            text-align: center;
        }

        .SortOfImportantStuff {
            color: green;
            font-family: Calibri;
            font-size: x-large;
            text-align: center;
        }

        /*ids always begin with a #  */
        /*it will look for all elements with id of ChangeButton*/
        #ChangeButton {
            background-color:orange;
        }

        /*for the style below: since there is no # or . - it will look for an HTML element*/
        /*so all div tags will follow this style*/
        div {
            color: blue;
            font-family: cursive;
            font-size: medium;
        }

        .footerStyle{
            font-family:'Lucida Sans';
            font-size: x-large;
        }
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <!--all the attributes of an object appear in red:-->
    <input id="ChangeButton" type="button" value="Change the look of this page." onclick="ChangeThis()" />
    <h1 class="ImportantStuff">Here we go - let's have some fun.</h1>
    <p>In case you'd rather be on some much funner web sites:</p>
    <br />
    <!--target = "_blank" makes the page open in a new window or tab-->
    <a href="http://www.cedarpoint.com" target="_blank">Cedar Point</a>
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.facebook.com" target="_blank">Face Book</a>
    <br />
    <a href="http://www.youtube.com" target="_blank">YouTube</a>
    <br />
    <div>
        <b>Places I'd like to visit:</b>
        <div>
            Alaska

            <img src="Images/Alaska.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Australia
            <img src="Images/Australia.jpg" />
        </div>
        <div>
            Maine
            <img src="Images/Maine.jpg" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <span id="footer1">Maybe someday I'll get to these places.</span>
    <br />
    <span id="footer2">Until then, I'll just save my money.</span>
    <script>
        function ChangeThis() {
            var allas = document.querySelectorAll("a");
            for (x = 0; x < allas.length; x++) {
                allas[x].setAttribute("class", "SortOfImportantStuff");
            }
            document.querySelector("p").style.color = "red";
            document.querySelector("p").style.backgroundColor = "green";
            var allimgs = document.querySelectorAll("img");
            for (x = 0; x < allimgs.length; x++) {
                allimgs[x].style.width = 250 + 'px';
                allimgs[x].style.height = 150 + 'px';
            }
            var InnerDivs = document.querySelectorAll("div div");
            for (x = 0; x < InnerDivs.length; x++) {
                InnerDivs[x].style.color = "red";

            }

            //CODE IN QUESTION
            document.querySelector("#footer1", ".footerStyle");

            //

            document.querySelector('#footer2').textContent = 'Happy Halloween';


        }
    </script>
```

Comment: `.querySelector` only takes a single argument. `document.querySelector('#footer').id = 'newIdHere';` or `document.querySelector('#footer').setAttribute('id', 'newIdHere');` would be the syntax. Of course, `document.getElementById('footer')` executes faster, so you might want to still use that if you're just getting by `id`.

Comment: Use your inspector after hitting `fn` and `f12` to see changes.

Comment: `'id'` is the actual attribute.

Comment: Still nothing: document.querySelector('#footer1').setAttribute('id', 'footerStyle');

Comment: It did change, when I ran your code.... but, after the change that `id` is no the same. You should really just change HTML `class` attribute values with `Element.classList.toggle` in your case.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer:

```js
document.querySelector('#footer1').setAttribute("class", "footerStyle");
```

Comment: While this code may answer the question, providing additional context regarding how and/or why it solves the problem would improve the answer's long-term value. You can find more information on how to write good answers in the help center: https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer . Good luck 

Comment: You can also set the [className](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/className) directly instead of using setAttribute.